# Why am I getting many suggested edits by anonymous users?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, anonymous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

While I've been approving suggested edits, I've seen many times that edit is proposed by an anonymous user. What is meaning of that? Most of time it's invalid.

> [image: proposed by an anonymous user]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anonymous visitors (anyone not logged in) can also suggest edits.

A lot of the time they misuse that feature to make a comment or ask a question; these edits should be rejected outright.

I suspect you are confusing 'approved' with 'suggested'. Do you have any examples of such suggested edits actually being approved (e.g. accepted by reviewers)? If so, please override the reviewer decisions.

Yes, we sometimes get crap from anonymous users this way, but there are also good contributions that come in this way, that we do not want to turn away. See [Do we have stats showing that anonymous edits are helpful?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120849/do-we-have-stats-showing-that-anonymous-edits-are-helpful).

Thus, removing the feature for anonymous users has been turned down before, see [Prevent suggested edits coming from anonymous users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83457/prevent-suggested-edits-coming-from-anonymous-users)

Comment: ya if ill get than ill defiantly do that

Comment: why this option when its i think misuse more thank 95%

Comment: See [Prevent suggested edits coming from anonymous users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83457) there are already some more restrictions in place for anonymous users suggesting edits. We do get a lot of good edits from anonymous as well, see [Do we have stats showing that anonymous edits are helpful?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120849)

Comment: I'd venture a guess and say that we get just as many crap edits from 1-rep new users as we do from flat-out anonymous users.

Answer (score 6):

Anonymous users are allowed to suggest improvements to posts like any user.
That's why they go up for review. Just reject it and move on. :)