# Reviewing Suggested Edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review

I have noticed lately since I have been reviewing more regularly on Stackoverflow, that there are a lot of people who don't properly review posts. A lot of people simply click "Approve" just to move along when the edit may be false.

Recently, I answered a question which was edited by an anonymous user (which I think should not be allowed). He made an addition and basically said my answer was crap. I don't mind if someone thinks my answer isn't correct or could be improved, but I don't see how anonymous user can even be allowed to edit, never mind write something like that. I looked at the review stats and was glad to find the majority of people declined it, however 1 users for some odd reason approved it.

So I have 2 suggestions:

1. Anonymous users should not be allowed to edit a post.
2. Either increase the rep needed to review suggested edits or set a small time limit before any actions can be take on the edit, so people actually read the changes that have been made, rather than taking the first action that they see.

Update:

If removing anonymous edits is a bit too much, then why not add recaptcha to them? It might prevent some of the spam edits.

Comment: Related: [Why am I getting many suggested edits by anonymous users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147293/147295#147295)

Comment: No, anonymous suggested edits are not going to go away.

Comment: And definitely related (possibly a dupe): [The current review system encourages fake reviews; some people upvote everything rather than actually fixing problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149621) and many more.

Comment: well if suggested edits won't be removed, what about adding a recatpcha for them. cause a lot of posts are being spammed with pointless edits

Comment: [The robo-approvers are killing my will to review edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155561) [What can we do to stop bad edits getting accepted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137784)

Comment: this is a flaw of current review system, see [What can we do to stop bad edits getting accepted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137784/165773), [The robo-approvers are killing my will to review edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155561/165773) and especially **[Please facilitate undoing the harm from bad suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122038/165773)**

Comment: It's not the anonymous edit suggestions that are the problem here. The problem lies with the robo-approvers.

Comment: Regarding captcha I think the system has other means of protection against spam bots. I am pretty sure that if bots could spam the edit suggestions we would have seen **thousands** of spam edits each day but as it stands, there are just few true spam edits which means the protection works and those are real people who post the spam.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't referring to bots. I was referring to normal people who suggest edits such as the one made to my answer on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Lodder: Yet the system worked, the edit was rejected. Yes, there was one auto-approver there, but in the end the system (which requires multiple reviewers) did it's job and the edit was rejected.

Comment: true but like I said, there was someone who approved this edit. What is there were 3 people? The edit would be completely approved.

Comment: @Lodder Then you roll back and curse the new review queues, like the rest of us.