# Who is the "anon" user from the database's perspective?

Tags: support, anonymous

Recently, we had a [tiny bit of drama](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16845/should-we-get-reputation-points-for-passing-review-tests) over on Ask Ubuntu Meta, which led a post to be anonymized (being owned by the user `anon`).

This piqued my interest for no particular reason, except for how the system keeps track of anonymous users.

Do they have a special User ID that effectively takes ownership of the post? Are they just a `null` user? In short, what, technically, makes `anon` tick?

Comment: Highly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292770 -- And I've almost got a really thorough answer written for that (over there there are different possibilities in PostHistory depending on the PostHistoryTypeId) except [I'm totally confused by the terminology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292783). Once I get that cleared up and post an answer there maybe it'll help here. But for the most part they are null, and Community is -1 (although certain actions do end up being attributed to Community and end up with a -1, but -1 does not imply "anonymous").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no user ID for "anon" - it's just a null user in the database. However, we also store a display name for each post in the database, which allows for some text to be displayed in the event there is no longer a user ID associated with the post (because it's null). This text gets changed to "anon" when staff disassociate a post from a user's profile. It also gets changed to a "userXXXXX" string when a user deletes their profile.